# normalize matrix data in python

Tags: python

I have a matrix whose rows represent EEG channels and columns represent time periods. The cells contain the intensity. If I now create a scatter plot of the different columns, showing on the X axis the relative distance of the electrodes (starting from the electrode with the highest intensity) and on the y axis the relative decrease of the intensity, I get a distribution that indicates a correlation of the two quantities. Now I want to create a single scatter plot that combines all data points. For this I need a suitable method to normalize the intensity decrease values.
I have already tried to normalize the whole thing by normalizing column by column, but the result does not seem to fully reflect what was clear in the individual scatter plots.

here is the code of the previous method:

```
def create_scatter_plot(matrix, electrode_names, calculate_distance, positions_df, threshold, min_values):
    n_rows, n_columns = matrix.shape
    
    normalized_intensity_diffs = []
    normalized_distances = []
    
    
    for i in range(n_columns):
        column = matrix[:, i]
        above_threshold = column > threshold
        if np.sum(above_threshold) < min_values:
            continue
        
        max_intensity_index = np.argmax(column)
        max_intensity = column[max_intensity_index]
        
        for j in range(n_rows):
            if j != max_intensity_index and above_threshold[j]:
                intensity_diff = column[j]/max_intensity
                normalized_intensity_diff = intensity_diff
                
                electrode_name1 = electrode_names[max_intensity_index]
                electrode_name2 = electrode_names[j]
                distance = calculate_distance(electrode_name1, electrode_name2, positions_df)
   
                
                normalized_intensity_diffs.append(normalized_intensity_diff)
                normalized_distances.append(distance)
    
    plt.scatter(normalized_distances, normalized_intensity_diffs)
    plt.xlabel("Distance")
    plt.ylabel("Intensity Difference")
    plt.show()
    return normalized_distances, normalized_intensity_diffs
```